# Vscode extention GitLens, How can turn off the feature as shown in the figure below?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

How can turn off the feature as shown in the figure below

[image]

Comment: have you searched the GitLens settings

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find the switch~

Comment: I don't even know how to express the feature.

Comment: many of the settings are clear not be of interest for this, so only a few remain, toggle them and see which one it is, that how I found it too

Answer (score 2):

For people still looking for an answer to this:

`"gitlens.codeLens.authors.enabled": true`

in settings.

Answer (score 2):

This decoration is part of a GitLens feature called CodeLens.

You can disable CodeLens in the JSON settings by setting `gitlens.codeLens.enabled` to `false`.

Alternatively, you can disable CodeLens in the GUI settings: search for `gitlens.codeLens.enabled` (or see Settings > Extensions > GitLens > Git CodeLens) and uncheck the checkbox.

Answer (score -1):

The feature you boxed in red is the point of the gitlens extension.  Disable gitlens extension to remove *1 author (zhuguoxi)*

Comment: You are suggesting an unnecessary overkill. This decoration is part of a GitLens feature called CodeLens and it can be disabled without disabling the GitLens extension altogether.